# Using Spatie's Laravel Permission Package, how can I assign multiple roles to a user?

Tags: laravel, user-permissions

I have many `accounts`, and many `users`. A user should have a role of `manager` in one `agency` but also a role of `customer` in another account.

Is it possible to use Spatie's Laravel permissions package (https://docs.spatie.be/laravel-permission/v3/introduction/) for this? For example a permission may exists called `can delete accounts`, but this should only be valid for certain `accounts`. The default functionality of the package would mean that a user with the permission `can delete accounts` would allow them to delete ANY account instead of only the account which they are a manager of.

I was thinking to have a many-to-many table `users_roles`, with fields `user_id`, `role_id`, `role_name`.

Is there any documentation on this? Or anyone accomplished this with the package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not out of the box with Spatie's Laravel Permission.

But you can write your own gates in Laravel: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authorization#gates

Check your current version docs as it might defer.

Comment: thanks. would writing my own gates mean I can still use the package?

Comment: They can coexist, yes. Just be careful how you implement and have tests.